# How to find Google-proprietary files (Docs, Slides, Sheets, Drawings, etc.)

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-search

My employer had a kind of "Google for life" plan for GSuite/Drive from years ago, but the current proposition from Google apparently is too costly and we must reduce space to respect a quota. The solution involves moving files around (looks like OneDrive will be the "for life" choice for now). But, since certain files (Google Docs, Google Sheets, etc.) don't work on OneDrive (or outside of Google), it's important to identify them, so they can be converted or whatever.

I tried using `type:document type:presentation type:spreadsheet type:drawing` in the advanced search in Google Drive, but sadly this also returns Microsoft Word .doc and docx files, .psd files, .xlsx files, etc.

How can I locate all the files that are Google-proprietary in a Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

For searching a single file type, instead of using the generic type (drawing, document, form, presentation, script, site, spreadsheet, among others) use the "corresponding" MIME types.

Note: Some "official" MIME types doesn't work, instead we have to use non-official.

In other words, instead of

```
type:document
```

use

```
type:application/vnd.google-apps.kix
```

and so on.

Unfortunately the Google Drive web app search hasn't boolean operators and apparently there is no way to search for multiple MIME types.

NOTE: `type:application/vnd.google-apps.script` return stand-alone and bounded scripts (shows the container)

---

Official MIME types taken from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types.
Non-official MIME types taken from https://gist.github.com/javan/7343255.

| Official MIME Type | Non-official MIME Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| application/vnd.google-apps.audio |  |  |
| application/vnd.google-apps.document | application/vnd.google-apps.kix | Google Docs |
| application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk |  | 3rd party shortcut |
| application/vnd.google-apps.drawing |  | Google Drawing |
| application/vnd.google-apps.file |  | Google Drive file |
| application/vnd.google-apps.folder |  | Google Drive folder |
| application/vnd.google-apps.form | application/vnd.google-apps.freebird | Google Forms |
| application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable |  | Google Fusion Tables |
| application/vnd.google-apps.map |  | Google My Maps |
| application/vnd.google-apps.photo |  |  |
| application/vnd.google-apps.presentation | application/vnd.google-apps.punch | Google Slides |
| application/vnd.google-apps.script |  | Google Apps Scripts |
| application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut |  | Shortcut |
| application/vnd.google-apps.site | `<required>` | Google Sites |
| application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet | application/vnd.google-apps.ritz | Google Sheets |
| application/vnd.google-apps.unknown |  |  |
| application/vnd.google-apps.video |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

One imperfect solution is to use the `-` operator to remove results that are not the files you want to find, e.g., `-.doc` excludes files matching that pattern.

Caveat: if you have a Google Docs file named `Letter.doc` that is a Word file converted to Google Docs, it will be (wrongly) excluded, because part of the file matches `-.doc`. As such, this answer is imperfect.

Here is an example search that seems to do a good job if you don't have converted files (it will likely require tweaking since I'm not sure what are all of the file types that match each `type:`):

```
type:drawing type:document type:spreadsheet type:presentation -.docx -.doc -.dot -.txt -.text -.log -.tmp -.temp -.ppt -.pptx -.xlsx -.xls -.xlt -.psd
```

I noticed that some old Macintosh word processor files (that don't have extensions in the file names) got recognized as documents, so again this solution isn't perfect.